# How can I set an empty alert

Tags: javascript

I have made a little game in Script. That's sort of arithmetic game. I asked 2+2-3=? and user have to give the answer. If the answer is right than alert will show congratulations and if answer is wrong then you are higher or lower than actual answer. But now I want to add another alert if someone not answering this question and leave the prompt empty and press enter than another alert will be display like You are looser. My question is; how can I set the value empty and alert. Here is what I tried and it didn't work. Please see the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number = prompt("count these numbers: 2+5-10+8=?");
    if (number == 5) {
        alert("Congratulations Your Answer is Correct");
    } else if (number > 5) {
        alert("Your answer is a little higher.");
    } else if (number < 5) {
        alert("Your answer is little lower than actual answer.");
    } else if (number == "null") {
        alert("You are looser!");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Just a wording note: your last alert message should be "You are loser!".

Comment: Grammatically, that should read "You are a loser!". Although that seems a bit harsh.

Comment: You are covering the case for eqaul to, greater than and less than. Why not just use "else" instead of testing the variable. Ex: `} else { alert("Answer was not understood, please try again."); }`

Answer (score 2):

I would parse the number so it's actually a `Number` type, instead of relying on the `==` to coerce the value for you. Then, you could check for `NaN` with the `isNaN` function, or better yet, leave off the `if` completely and just make it an `else`:

```
var number = parseInt(prompt("count these numbers: 2+5-10+8=?"), 10);
if (number === 5) {
    alert("Congratulations! Your answer is correct.");
} else if (number > 5) {
    alert("Your answer is a little higher.");
} else if (number < 5) {
    alert("Your answer is little lower than actual answer.");
} else {
    alert("You are a loser!");
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KebNN/

Answer (score 1):

Just compare it to an empty string:

```
if (number == '') {
    // ...
```

Also, if you want to alert the same message on "Cancel" clicks, you can simply check whether number evaluates to false:

```
if (!number) {
    // ...
```

Comment: It's not working. I want if a user left the prompt empty and press enter than an alert will show. But as your code it is showing another alert Your answer is little lower than actual answer.

Comment: It won't get to this else-if if the conditionals are left in their current order, because `'' < 5` is truthy. See my answer for an alternative solution.

Comment: You will need to put it at the very beginning!

Comment: @AzibYaqoob You're welcome! But you should also consider FishBasketGordo's answer - it's the cleaner way to deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Use (answer == null || answer == undefined || answer == '')

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
} else if (number == "" || isNaN(number)) {
    alert("You are looser!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but is this what you're looking for?

```
alert("");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user presses cancel on a prompt, the value will be `null`. By comparing it with `===`, we make sure the answer isn't 0 (`0 == null` is true).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var number = prompt("count these numbers: 2+5-10+8=?");
    if (number === null) {
        alert("You are loser!");            
    } else if (number == 5) {
        alert("Congratulations Your Answer is Correct");
    } else if (number > 5) {
        alert("Your answer is a little higher.");
    } else if (number < 5) {
        alert("Your answer is little lower than actual answer.");
    }
</script>​
```

Answer (score -1):

You have accounted for all of the possible results except for null you could just add a else at the end of the first if statement as a catch all.. I.E. if the user leaves it blank or enters an invalid character.

```
if( number == 5 ) {
   alert( "Congratulations Your Answer is Correct" );
} else if ( number > 5  ) {
   alert( "Your answer is a little higher." );
} else if ( number < 5 ) {
   alert( "Your answer is little lower than actual answer." );
} else {
   alert("You are looser!");
}
```

.....

Comment: I don't understand why i was marked as a negative 1 for my posting when it is the same as the one with 2 up...